# Java class functions and members

Tags: java, nashorn

I am trying to improve my scripts by altering some code. What I want is to make use of JS members. I know I can do this with AbstractScriptObject by overriding getMember.

Now comes the problem, I also have methods in this class that I want to call, but apparently I cannot call them anymore because it acts like a JS object now and it won't recgonize my methods anymore.

Is there any way so I can have members and java methods that I can call within a script? (Maybe something that converts my java methods to js functions?)

I want to do something like this in scripts:
`if (dog.name == "")`
and
`dog.doSomething(args)`

Thanks in advance,
Kevin

Comment: Can you show an actual example? eg a Class, and how you are adding it to your bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to expose your "methods" as script "functions". i.e., getMember should return further JSObject implementations that are "callable" (isFunction returns true and you override "call").

Comment: Do you perhaps know if `Object thiz` is the actual object where I use the function with? Because I am trying to make some sort of class now that uses reflection searching the method from the instance by name and parameters Class<?>

Comment: "thiz" would be the "method" containing JSObject (on which you called the method from script). In any case, you can use anonymous inner classes and access underlying Java object(s) from surrounding scope.

Comment: Thank you. I've made a default class that uses reflection to see whether the method exists and calls it. Now I can use members and the methods of the class are automatically exposed. Line in the `call` override: `return thiz.getClass().getMethod(method, Arrays.stream(args).map(o -> changeIfPrimitive(o.getClass())).toArray(Class<?>[]::new)).invoke(thiz, args);` I only use primitive types for Integers, Doubles etc, so I convert them to primitives if it has a primitive type.